# Magento 1.9.3.8 problem with folders permission

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, permissions

I have magento installed in a cloud server and folder public_html/.
Some days ago because the permissions of the files was a messed up I used Magento's instruction's to set permissions from the beginning:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} +
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} +
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} +
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} +
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} +
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} +
```

I've done this logged in with ssh with root user. Site is working but all magento cron jobs are not.

Server is using Nginx as:

> user:www-data

Magento is installed with:

> user:wpaper

All files and subfolders now in public_html/ are:

> owner:www-data & group:wpaper

Both user **wpaper** and user **www-data** are in the same groups.
Groups are **wpaper** and **www-data**.
What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Does everything work when you set the user to www-data?

Comment: @brentwpeterson Site is working.....but crons are not....I am still looking...